# Getting blank result when decode image using base64_decode laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have seen people use base64_decode to decode image but I want to decode the image from my database and show it in my view form. Any ideas?

After I did some more research I found out that I need to convert it into image after decoding but how do I do that? Thanks in advance

Controller:

```
 public function getInfo($id) {
  $data = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();
 return view('test',compact('qualification','data'));
}
```

View.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
   <b>Signature: </b>{{base64_decode($object->signature)}}<br><br>
@endforeach
```

Route:

```
Route::get('user/show/{id}','HomeController@getInfo')->name("user.show");
```

Comment: Have you saved it as base_64 in database ?

Comment: I just used $table->binary('signature'); when creating the table and request from what the user had drawn and just save it into the database

Answer (score 0):

At the time of saving you can save as (if you are using laravel image intervention [package](http://image.intervention.io/))

```
 $images = Input::file('images');
 foreach($images as $image){
   $imageDb = (string)Image::make($img)->encode('data-url');
   // save the image in database now 
 }
```

You can save `$imageDb` in image tale of database and you can fetch image from database and show like normally providing the src attribute in img tag like below in your blade file

Comment: But if I were to do how do I decode it? Do I need to do something like this in my controller? (eg: $imageDb = (string)Image::make($img)->decode('data-url');). Because if possible I want to decode my image in my view.blade file since there might be a chance of undefined variable happening if I were to put in the controller and pass it to the view page

Comment: This package function takes care of this, this will save in desired format, and you have to just fetch the image. You can use above method and save in database, in the view you will pass the image table data, so you can use directly there, Are you using image intervention package ?. otherwise you have to save in the specific format uri

Comment: I am not using the image intervention package, so was just thinking maybe I could try it out but is there really no other method to decode it?

Comment: Yes, there is method to do it in plain php. it is better to encode and save in a specific format, so while showing you don't need to decode it. I am updating the answer

Comment: I just saw some video where people used the image intervention package and they have to manually upload the image, so is it possible to upload the signature captured by user and automatically send it to database?

Comment: Ya, You can directly save the url in database by calling this `->encode('data-url');` function on image object, in my example `$img` is single image taken from file, if you have multiple you can loop through it and put the above code inside the loop.  it is actually save in the specific format, i.e `data:image/png;base64, your base 64 converted string`

Comment: oh I see will try it then